# PHP $_SESSION variable causing errors with mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to select data from mySQL database,
I execute the following code:

```
 <?php $_SESSION["dog_park"] = $_GET['keyword'] ?>              

                <div class="review"> <!-- Creating a div with the class 'review -->


                <!-- but POST varibale in here for dog park name -->
                    <h1><?php echo $_SESSION["dog_park"]; ?></h1>




<table border="1" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Park Name</th>
            <th>Street</th>
            <th>Suburb</th>
            <th>Dog Park Area (m2)</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php

        $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM dog_parks.items where suburb = '$_SESSION[dog_park]'");
        $result->execute();
        for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><label><?php echo $row['Park_Name']; ?></label></td>
            <td><label><?php echo $row['Street']; ?></label></td>
            <td><label><?php echo $row['Suburb']; ?></label></td>
            <td><label><?php echo $row['Dog_Park_Area_(m2)']; ?></label></td>

        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When that script executes it displays the following error:
[image: Error Message]

It has something to do with the session variable, if i enter a static value for    the mySQL query it will display table data correctly, but fail when the $_SESSION variable is present.

Comment: The question isn't about SQL injections, but the issue the user is having is the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That string contains quotes, that breaks your SQL string encapsulation. Use the prepared statements as they are meant to be, parameterized, and the issue will be gone.

```
$result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM dog_parks.items where suburb = ?");
$result->execute(array($_SESSION[dog_park]));
```

You can read more:

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php
[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

As is your query was running as:

> SELECT * FROM dog_parks.items where suburb = ''Tramway''

(roughly, if you'd included text of error message, not image I could supply real query)

Which is invalid because `''` is what you are comparing. The `Tramway''` it doesn't know what to do with. This coincidentally is how SQL injections occur.

Comment: Error message was fixed, thanks.
Had to add quotes around $_SESSION['dog_park']   
No table data being displayed, any ideas??

Comment: You read my whole answer? The `'dog_park'` wasn't the main point of my answer.. If `suburb` doesn't equal your exact string you will get no records, does your record have quotes in it?

Comment: @deluxenathan so the issue is resolved?

Comment: Not quite i'm having other issues with sessions, but not related to the post.
All good.

Comment: Okay, if this resolved the issue please mark answer as such.